# How to "Save as Table" on Bigquery and define the location of the table?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm querying data with BigQuery in two different projects in Google Cloud. Both projects have the tables with Data Location (table>details> Data Location) as "US".

When I query it and get a result I want to save it as another table. So using the BQ UI I try hitting the "save as table" button on top the query results.

As I said, both projects have their data in the US but when clicking here I get the following error message:

> Errors: Cannot read and write in different locations: source: US,
>   destination: EU

But I didn't define EU anywhere.

Does anyone know how I can change that parameter from the BigQuery UI? Or even how to write it straight in the Query

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In BigQuery, location is assigned at the dataset level. Perhaps the destination dataset is an EU dataset? Does "Save as Table" work if you try to save to a newly-created dataset?

You can also click "Show Options" and set the destination table for your query if you want to write the output of your query directly to the target table.

Answer (score 0):

So you have to select dataset location while creating the dataset. ex:

```
bq mk --data_location US --default_table_expiration 3600 --description "This is my Market  Dataset." market
```

Apart from that if you are using the Goole cloud storage then that need ot be either Regional or Multi regional depending upon your requirement.